# Combine with import

Tags: import, combine

The following program gives erors, which means that it doesn't work. I haven't not found what the problem is. If you can find the problem or work the following program, please write the new program here. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[twosided]{combine} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%%%%%Head and Foot%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{The preview}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{PREVIEW}
\fancyfoot[R]{City}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\title{Abtract}
\author{PREVIEW}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{chap1}
\begin{papers}
\import{article}
\end{papers}
\end{document}
```

Article is as follows:

```
%%%%%article%%%%%
\documentclass {article}
\begin{document}

\date{}
\title{Article}
\author{The author}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
$A$=$B$ and \cite{1}.
\end{abstract}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{1} The author, \textit{Article}, Journal (2018), 1-5.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
%%%%%%

> %%%%%%%%%%%DOC.log%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% This is pdfTeX, Version
> 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.10.16)  17 OCT 2018 16:39 entering extended mode
> **./Doc.tex (Doc.tex LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 1 Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded. ("C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\combine\combine.cls" Document Class:
> combine 2010/07/10 v0.7a collection of documents  ("C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty" Package: keyval
> 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC) \KV@toks@=\toks14 )
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls" Document
> Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo" File:
> size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option) )
> \c@part=\count79 \c@section=\count80 \c@subsection=\count81
> \c@subsubsection=\count82 \c@paragraph=\count83
> \c@subparagraph=\count84 \c@figure=\count85 \c@table=\count86
> \abovecaptionskip=\skip41 \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
> \bibindent=\dimen102 ) \c@colpage=\count87 \c@c@lctr=\count88
> \c@ltocfnum=\write3 \c@lloffnum=\write4 \c@llotfnum=\write5
> \c@bodytitle=\count89 \toctitleindent=\skip43 \tocauthorindent=\skip44
> \tocpubindent=\skip45 \toctocindent=\skip46 ) ("C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty" Package: fancyhdr
> 2017/06/30 v3.9a Extensive control of page headers and footer s
> \f@nch@headwidth=\skip47 \f@nch@O@elh=\skip48 \f@nch@O@erh=\skip49
> \f@nch@O@olh=\skip50 \f@nch@O@orh=\skip51 \f@nch@O@elf=\skip52
> \f@nch@O@erf=\skip53 \f@nch@O@olf=\skip54 \f@nch@O@orf=\skip55 )
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
> Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
> \@emptytoks=\toks15 \symAMSa=\mathgroup4 \symAMSb=\mathgroup5 LaTeX
> Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
> (Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106. )
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty" Package:
> amsmath 2016/11/05 v2.16a AMS math features \@mathmargin=\skip56
> 
> For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty" Package:
> amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
> 
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty" File:
> amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions \@emptytoks=\toks16
> \ex@=\dimen103 )) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty" Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols \pmbraise@=\dimen104 ) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty" Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names ) \inf@bad=\count90 LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on
> input line 213. \uproot@=\count91 \leftroot@=\count92 LaTeX Info:
> Redefining \overline on input line 375. \classnum@=\count93
> \DOTSCASE@=\count94 LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 472.
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 475. LaTeX Info: Redefining
> \cdots on input line 596. \Mathstrutbox@=\box26 \strutbox@=\box27
> \big@size=\dimen105 LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML
> on input line 712. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS
> on input line 713. \macc@depth=\count95 \c@MaxMatrixCols=\count96
> \dotsspace@=\muskip10 \c@parentequation=\count97 \dspbrk@lvl=\count98
> \tag@help=\toks17 \row@=\count99 \column@=\count100
> \maxfields@=\count101 \andhelp@=\toks18 \eqnshift@=\dimen106
> \alignsep@=\dimen107 \tagshift@=\dimen108 \tagwidth@=\dimen109
> \totwidth@=\dimen110 \lineht@=\dimen111 \@envbody=\toks19
> \multlinegap=\skip57 \multlinetaggap=\skip58
> \mathdisplay@stack=\toks20 LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line
> 2817. LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2818. ) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty" Package: amssymb
> 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols )
> 
> LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
>     [twosided].
> 
> (Doc.aux) \openout1 = `Doc.aux'.
> 
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line
> 20. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 20. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 20. LaTeX Font Info:   
> ... okay o
```

Comment: Without knowing what's in the files `article1.tex` and `article.tex`, it's probably impossible to help you with this. I suggest you prepare a [minimal example code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/2417)  that reproduces the problem.

Comment: `\begin{thebibliography}{9}` has to end with `\end{thebibliography}`

Comment: With this example code and `\end{thebibliography}` inserted as suggested by @koleygr, I don't get any errors.

Comment: So, does it solves your problem? If so, I can write an answer or you may write an analytic answer of the steps followed to solve your problem

Comment: Sorry, i can not compile the above document with texwork. It gives the same eror.  Could you please put the document compiled by you here?

Comment: @Nobody --- I get a 3 page pdf, but the site doesn't provide a convenient way to upload these. It would be easier if you told us what the error message is, and then we will be able to suggest ways to fix it.

Comment: The eror is as follows:                                                                                          LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [twosided].

(Doc.aux) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd") (Doc.toc) [1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] [2] (article.tex (article.aux)

Comment: That's not an error; it's a warning. The pdf should still be generated (unless there is some other problem).

Comment: When i compile the document, the above message appears at console line. After this message, the program can not proceed. It doesn't generate pdf file.The program code is the same wih the above program code. I use miktex 2.9.6210. May it be the problem giving this eror?

Comment: OK, edit your question and add the complete contents of the file `Doc.log`. It should be possible to work out what's going on from there.

Comment: I've looked at the `.log` file you posted, and it's very, very strange. Are you sure you haven't missed off the end of the file? If that really is the complete log, then try deleting all generated files (including `.aux` , `.toc`,  etc.) and compiling again. Is the log file any different?

Comment: I tried a MWE with simple documents and the problem is real. I think `combine` is too old (form 2010 if I am not wrong) and maybe there are some bugs.

Comment: @sigur --- Confirmed. I can reproduce the problem with TeXLive 2018, but the MWE works with TeXLive 2015.

Comment: @IanThompson, 2015!! Ow, complicated now. Some updates to the package would be good.

Comment: @sigur it seems David Carlisle had an answer to this issue that still works with TeX Live 2018

Answer (score 1):

The "combine function" as its name suggests add files together thus there would only be one main \begin{document} and \end{document} and the command seems to stumble when it mishandles others in the included file. I commented these out in the mwe import file and TeXworks compiled a .pdf, however as Ian Thompson pointed out, this is in contradiction to the package documentation which says

"The command \import{`<texfile>`} is a cross between the \input and \include
commands, and should only be used within a papers environment. `<texfile>` is the
name of a LATEX file without the .tex extension. For example, \import{fred} will
attempt to read in a file called fred.tex. The `<texfile>` should be a complete  LATEX file from \documentclass to \end{document}"

Thus it would appear other pre-requisites must be met to suit this package.

The fancy header seems to be root of the problem and when commented out the included file was again accepted and compiled to .pdf, but not as desired. On searching that combination for common problems we get a perfect solution suggested by David Carlisle in [combine broken by fancyheader](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348185/is-the-combine-documentclass-broken-when-using-the-fancyhdr-package-or-vice-vers)

```
    \documentclass[twosided]{combine} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%%%%%Head and Foot%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{The preview}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{PREVIEW}
\fancyfoot[R]{City}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\title{Abtract}
\author{PREVIEW}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{chap1}
\begin{papers}

% solution as recommended by David Carlisle
\makeatletter\let\@makecol\latex@makecol\makeatother

\import{article}
\end{papers}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually I think the purpose of the `combine` class is to allow the import of entire LaTeX documents, without editing the preamble or removing `\begin{document}`, etc. See the [package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/combine).

Answer (score -1):

You should write \input{article} instead of \import{article} if you want to write references manually. When "input" is used, the references will look like [?] in the main document. Besides you should delete \begin{document} and \end{document} while using \input in the document. When used \input, we meet the other problem. This problem is that automatically, the references can't be written. As said by @sigur, when some packages used in document are updated, this problem may be solved but i don't know which packages should be updated.

Comment: `\input{}` is not the correct way to use `combine`. It only takes the content of the whole file and insert it into the main one. There will be a lot of errors regarding multiple use of `\title{}` and `\author{}` and so on...